# Two properties for same website with Universal Analytics

Tags: analytics, universal-analytics

I need to track a website with Universal Analytics in two different properties of the same account.

Following a guide here http://www.tjkelly.com/blog/google-analytics-two-tracking-codes-on-same-page-2014/ I put this as last solution:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create','UA-xxxxxxx-1','domain.co');
ga('create','UA-yyyyyyyy-2',{'name':'b'});
ga('send','pageview');
ga('b.send','pageview');
```

Is this correct? It seems to work but it's pretty different from the guidelines https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers and

Comment: Sorry, but it's the same code :)

Comment: What do you see in your real time reports? Maybe that will answer your question.

Comment: It's pretty similar, but what's the difference from setting "auto" to "domain name" in predefined tracker, and in the second tracker doesn't set it at all?

Comment: I see the same stuff. But maybe I'm not considering something else.

Comment: The 'auto' setting just says to set the cookie at the highest available domain possible, which in this case is domain.com. Leaving the cookie domain blank does the same thing and GA will again set the cookie to the highest domain availability. Defining the cookie domain sets the cookie domain to exactly that.

Comment: Thanks! This is the complete answer. Why don't you copy this as an answer instead of a comment? So I can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'auto' setting just says to set the cookie at the highest available domain possible, which in this case is domain.com. Leaving the cookie domain blank does the same thing and GA will again set the cookie to the highest domain available. Defining the cookie domain sets the cookie domain to exactly that.